# extern class object not working :S

Tags: c++, class, directx-11

moving a global class object into its corresponding `cpp` file so i can declare it as an `extern` in order to use it in multiple files to avoid re-declaration compile errors.

Models.h

```
#ifndef MODELS_H
#define MODELS_H

#include <xnamath.h>

class Models {
    public:
        ID3D11Buffer* meshVertBuff;
        ID3D11Buffer* meshIndexBuff;
        std::vector<int> meshSubsetIndexStart;
        std::vector<int> meshSubsetTexture;

        int meshSubsets;
        XMMATRIX Player;
};
#endif
```

Models.cpp

```
#include "Models.h"

Models Model_1;
Models Model_2;
```

Main.cpp

```
#include "Input.h"
#include "Models.h"
#include "Player.h"
#include "Camera.h"


extern Camera MainCamera;
extern My_Player    mainPlayer;
extern Models   Model_1;
extern Models   Model_2;
```

oddly it's not working and i can't see why as i just get a ton of XNAMATH errors when i moved the class objects to `model.cpp`, if they're in `model.h` it's fine but then i cant use it in other modules. :S any help is appreciated.

errors -

```
Error   173 error C1003: error count exceeds 100; stopping compilation  C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft DirectX SDK (June 2010)\Include\xnamath.h  429
Error   103 error C2040: '_XMMATRIX::operator ()' : 'int &(UINT,UINT)' differs in levels of indirection from 'int (UINT,UINT)'  C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft DirectX SDK (June 2010)\Include\xnamath.h  361
Error   28  error C2059: syntax error : ')' C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft DirectX SDK (June 2010)\Include\xnamath.h  159
Error   37  error C2059: syntax error : ')' C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft DirectX SDK (June 2010)\Include\xnamath.h  160
Error   57  error C2059: syntax error : ')' C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft DirectX SDK (June 2010)\Include\xnamath.h  324
Error   110 error C2059: syntax error : ')' C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft DirectX SDK (June 2010)\Include\xnamath.h  363
Error   114 error C2059: syntax error : ')' C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft DirectX SDK (June 2010)\Include\xnamath.h  366
Error   118 error C2059: syntax error : ')' C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft DirectX SDK (June 2010)\Include\xnamath.h  367
Error   119 error C2059: syntax error : '}' C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft DirectX SDK (June 2010)\Include\xnamath.h  372
Error   121 error C2059: syntax error : '}' C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft DirectX SDK (June 2010)\Include\xnamath.h  372
Error   104 error C2059: syntax error : 'return'    C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft DirectX SDK (June 2010)\Include\xnamath.h  361
Error   89  error C2061: syntax error : identifier 'CONST'  C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft DirectX SDK (June 2010)\Include\xnamath.h  358
Error   137 error C2061: syntax error : identifier 'CONST'  C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft DirectX SDK (June 2010)\Include\xnamath.h  398
Error   139 error C2061: syntax error : identifier 'CONST'  C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft DirectX SDK (June 2010)\Include\xnamath.h  400
Error   147 error C2061: syntax error : identifier 'CONST'  C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft DirectX SDK (June 2010)\Include\xnamath.h  412
Error   149 error C2061: syntax error : identifier 'CONST'  C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft DirectX SDK (June 2010)\Include\xnamath.h  414
Error   162 error C2061: syntax error : identifier 'CONST'  C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft DirectX SDK (June 2010)\Include\xnamath.h  430
Error   166 error C2061: syntax error : identifier 'CONST'  C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft DirectX SDK (June 2010)\Include\xnamath.h  432
Error   168 error C2061: syntax error : identifier 'CONST'  C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft DirectX SDK (June 2010)\Include\xnamath.h  434
Error   49  error C2061: syntax error : identifier 'FLOAT'  C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft DirectX SDK (June 2010)\Include\xnamath.h  316
Error   51  error C2061: syntax error : identifier 'FLOAT'  C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft DirectX SDK (June 2010)\Include\xnamath.h  317
Error   53  error C2061: syntax error : identifier 'FLOAT'  C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft DirectX SDK (June 2010)\Include\xnamath.h  323
Error   58  error C2061: syntax error : identifier 'FLOAT'  C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft DirectX SDK (June 2010)\Include\xnamath.h  325
Error   87  error C2061: syntax error : identifier 'FLOAT'  C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft DirectX SDK (June 2010)\Include\xnamath.h  354
Error   135 error C2061: syntax error : identifier 'FLOAT'  C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft DirectX SDK (June 2010)\Include\xnamath.h  397
Error   145 error C2061: syntax error : identifier 'FLOAT'  C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft DirectX SDK (June 2010)\Include\xnamath.h  411
Error   164 error C2061: syntax error : identifier 'FLOAT'  C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft DirectX SDK (June 2010)\Include\xnamath.h  431
Error   160 error C2061: syntax error : identifier 'HALF'   C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft DirectX SDK (June 2010)\Include\xnamath.h  429
Error   141 error C2065: '_x' : undeclared identifier   C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft DirectX SDK (June 2010)\Include\xnamath.h  397
Error   151 error C2065: '_x' : undeclared identifier   C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft DirectX SDK (June 2010)\Include\xnamath.h  411
Error   170 error C2065: '_x' : undeclared identifier   C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft DirectX SDK (June 2010)\Include\xnamath.h  429
Error   142 error C2065: '_y' : undeclared identifier   C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft DirectX SDK (June 2010)\Include\xnamath.h  397
Error   152 error C2065: '_y' : undeclared identifier   C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft DirectX SDK (June 2010)\Include\xnamath.h  411
Error   171 error C2065: '_y' : undeclared identifier   C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft DirectX SDK (June 2010)\Include\xnamath.h  429
Error   107 error C2065: 'CONST' : undeclared identifier    C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft DirectX SDK (June 2010)\Include\xnamath.h  363
Error   111 error C2065: 'CONST' : undeclared identifier    C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft DirectX SDK (June 2010)\Include\xnamath.h  366
Error   115 error C2065: 'CONST' : undeclared identifier    C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft DirectX SDK (June 2010)\Include\xnamath.h  367
Error   153 error C2065: 'pArray' : undeclared identifier   C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft DirectX SDK (June 2010)\Include\xnamath.h  412
Error   34  error C2086: 'int FLOAT' : redefinition C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft DirectX SDK (June 2010)\Include\xnamath.h  160
Error   97  error C2143: syntax error : missing ';' before '&'  C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft DirectX SDK (June 2010)\Include\xnamath.h  361
Error   106 error C2143: syntax error : missing ';' before '&'  C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft DirectX SDK (June 2010)\Include\xnamath.h  363
Error   123 error C2143: syntax error : missing ';' before '&'  C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft DirectX SDK (June 2010)\Include\xnamath.h  378
Error   91  error C2143: syntax error : missing ';' before '('  C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft DirectX SDK (June 2010)\Include\xnamath.h  360
Error   29  error C2143: syntax error : missing ';' before '{'  C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft DirectX SDK (June 2010)\Include\xnamath.h  159
Error   38  error C2143: syntax error : missing ';' before '{'  C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft DirectX SDK (June 2010)\Include\xnamath.h  160
Error   120 error C2143: syntax error : missing ';' before '}'  C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft DirectX SDK (June 2010)\Include\xnamath.h  372
Error   108 error C2146: syntax error : missing ')' before identifier '_XMMATRIX'   C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft DirectX SDK (June 2010)\Include\xnamath.h  363
Error   112 error C2146: syntax error : missing ')' before identifier '_XMMATRIX'   C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft DirectX SDK (June 2010)\Include\xnamath.h  366
Error   116 error C2146: syntax error : missing ')' before identifier '_XMMATRIX'   C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft DirectX SDK (June 2010)\Include\xnamath.h  367
Error   26  error C2146: syntax error : missing ')' before identifier 'fDegrees'    C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft DirectX SDK (June 2010)\Include\xnamath.h  159
Error   35  error C2146: syntax error : missing ')' before identifier 'fRadians'    C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft DirectX SDK (June 2010)\Include\xnamath.h  160
Error   54  error C2146: syntax error : missing ')' before identifier 'S'   C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft DirectX SDK (June 2010)\Include\xnamath.h  324
Error   40  error C2146: syntax error : missing ';' before identifier '__vector4i'  C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft DirectX SDK (June 2010)\Include\xnamath.h  217
Error   60  error C2146: syntax error : missing ';' before identifier '_11' C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft DirectX SDK (June 2010)\Include\xnamath.h  342
Error   66  error C2146: syntax error : missing ';' before identifier '_21' C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft DirectX SDK (June 2010)\Include\xnamath.h  343
Error   72  error C2146: syntax error : missing ';' before identifier '_31' C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft DirectX SDK (June 2010)\Include\xnamath.h  344
Error   78  error C2146: syntax error : missing ';' before identifier '_41' C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft DirectX SDK (June 2010)\Include\xnamath.h  345
Error   126 error C2146: syntax error : missing ';' before identifier 'HALF'    C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft DirectX SDK (June 2010)\Include\xnamath.h  386
Error   43  error C2146: syntax error : missing ';' before identifier 'i'   C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft DirectX SDK (June 2010)\Include\xnamath.h  246
Error   84  error C2146: syntax error : missing ';' before identifier 'm'   C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft DirectX SDK (June 2010)\Include\xnamath.h  347
Error   46  error C2146: syntax error : missing ';' before identifier 'u'   C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft DirectX SDK (June 2010)\Include\xnamath.h  260
Error   129 error C2146: syntax error : missing ';' before identifier 'x'   C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft DirectX SDK (June 2010)\Include\xnamath.h  391
Error   154 error C2146: syntax error : missing ';' before identifier 'x'   C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft DirectX SDK (June 2010)\Include\xnamath.h  423
Error   31  error C2146: syntax error : missing ';' before identifier 'XMConvertToDegrees'  C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft DirectX SDK (June 2010)\Include\xnamath.h  160
Error   23  error C2146: syntax error : missing ';' before identifier 'XMConvertToRadians'  C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft DirectX SDK (June 2010)\Include\xnamath.h  159
Error   132 error C2146: syntax error : missing ';' before identifier 'y'   C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft DirectX SDK (June 2010)\Include\xnamath.h  392
Error   157 error C2146: syntax error : missing ';' before identifier 'y'   C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft DirectX SDK (June 2010)\Include\xnamath.h  424
Error   105 error C2238: unexpected token(s) preceding ';'  C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft DirectX SDK (June 2010)\Include\xnamath.h  361
Error   55  error C2365: 'operator *' : redefinition; previous definition was 'function'    C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft DirectX SDK (June 2010)\Include\xnamath.h  324
Error   117 error C2365: 'operator *' : redefinition; previous definition was 'function'    C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft DirectX SDK (June 2010)\Include\xnamath.h  367
Error   113 error C2365: 'operator *=' : redefinition; previous definition was 'function'   C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft DirectX SDK (June 2010)\Include\xnamath.h  366
Error   24  error C2433: 'FLOAT' : '__forceinline' not permitted on data declarations   C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft DirectX SDK (June 2010)\Include\xnamath.h  159
Error   32  error C2433: 'FLOAT' : '__forceinline' not permitted on data declarations   C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft DirectX SDK (June 2010)\Include\xnamath.h  160
Error   56  error C2440: 'initializing' : cannot convert from 'int' to 'XMVECTOR'   C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft DirectX SDK (June 2010)\Include\xnamath.h  324
Error   30  error C2447: '{' : missing function header (old-style formal list?) C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft DirectX SDK (June 2010)\Include\xnamath.h  159
Error   39  error C2447: '{' : missing function header (old-style formal list?) C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft DirectX SDK (June 2010)\Include\xnamath.h  160
Error   125 error C2530: 'CXMMATRIX' : references must be initialized   C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft DirectX SDK (June 2010)\Include\xnamath.h  378
Error   136 error C2535: '_XMFLOAT2::_XMFLOAT2(void)' : member function already defined or declared C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft DirectX SDK (June 2010)\Include\xnamath.h  397
Error   138 error C2535: '_XMFLOAT2::_XMFLOAT2(void)' : member function already defined or declared C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft DirectX SDK (June 2010)\Include\xnamath.h  398
Error   161 error C2535: '_XMHALF2::_XMHALF2(void)' : member function already defined or declared   C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft DirectX SDK (June 2010)\Include\xnamath.h  429
Error   163 error C2535: '_XMHALF2::_XMHALF2(void)' : member function already defined or declared   C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft DirectX SDK (June 2010)\Include\xnamath.h  430
Error   165 error C2535: '_XMHALF2::_XMHALF2(void)' : member function already defined or declared   C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft DirectX SDK (June 2010)\Include\xnamath.h  431
Error   167 error C2535: '_XMHALF2::_XMHALF2(void)' : member function already defined or declared   C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft DirectX SDK (June 2010)\Include\xnamath.h  432
Error   88  error C2535: '_XMMATRIX::_XMMATRIX(void)' : member function already defined or declared C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft DirectX SDK (June 2010)\Include\xnamath.h  354
Error   90  error C2535: '_XMMATRIX::_XMMATRIX(void)' : member function already defined or declared C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft DirectX SDK (June 2010)\Include\xnamath.h  358
Error   146 error C2535: 'XMFLOAT2A::XMFLOAT2A(void)' : member function already defined or declared C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft DirectX SDK (June 2010)\Include\xnamath.h  411
Error   148 error C2535: 'XMFLOAT2A::XMFLOAT2A(void)' : member function already defined or declared C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft DirectX SDK (June 2010)\Include\xnamath.h  412
Error   102 error C2556: 'int &_XMMATRIX::operator ()(UINT,UINT)' : overloaded function differs only by return type from 'int _XMMATRIX::operator ()(UINT,UINT)'    C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft DirectX SDK (June 2010)\Include\xnamath.h  361
Error   144 error C2614: '_XMFLOAT2' : illegal member initialization: 'x' is not a base or member   C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft DirectX SDK (June 2010)\Include\xnamath.h  397
Error   143 error C2614: '_XMFLOAT2' : illegal member initialization: 'y' is not a base or member   C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft DirectX SDK (June 2010)\Include\xnamath.h  397
Error   172 error C2614: '_XMHALF2' : illegal member initialization: 'y' is not a base or member    C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft DirectX SDK (June 2010)\Include\xnamath.h  429
Error   95  error C2719: 'Column': formal parameter with __declspec(align('16')) won't be aligned   C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft DirectX SDK (June 2010)\Include\xnamath.h  360
Error   100 error C2719: 'Column': formal parameter with __declspec(align('16')) won't be aligned   C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft DirectX SDK (June 2010)\Include\xnamath.h  361
Error   94  error C2719: 'Row': formal parameter with __declspec(align('16')) won't be aligned  C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft DirectX SDK (June 2010)\Include\xnamath.h  360
Error   99  error C2719: 'Row': formal parameter with __declspec(align('16')) won't be aligned  C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft DirectX SDK (June 2010)\Include\xnamath.h  361
Error   50  error C2805: binary 'operator *=' has too few parameters    C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft DirectX SDK (June 2010)\Include\xnamath.h  316
Error   59  error C2805: binary 'operator /' has too few parameters C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft DirectX SDK (June 2010)\Include\xnamath.h  325
Error   52  error C2805: binary 'operator /=' has too few parameters    C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft DirectX SDK (June 2010)\Include\xnamath.h  317
Error   140 error C2805: binary 'operator =' has too few parameters C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft DirectX SDK (June 2010)\Include\xnamath.h  400
Error   150 error C2805: binary 'operator =' has too few parameters C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft DirectX SDK (June 2010)\Include\xnamath.h  414
Error   169 error C2805: binary 'operator =' has too few parameters C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft DirectX SDK (June 2010)\Include\xnamath.h  434
Error   93  error C3646: 'CONST' : unknown override specifier   C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft DirectX SDK (June 2010)\Include\xnamath.h  360
Error   25  error C4430: missing type specifier - int assumed. Note: C++ does not support default-int   C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft DirectX SDK (June 2010)\Include\xnamath.h  159
Error   27  error C4430: missing type specifier - int assumed. Note: C++ does not support default-int   C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft DirectX SDK (June 2010)\Include\xnamath.h  159
Error   33  error C4430: missing type specifier - int assumed. Note: C++ does not support default-int   C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft DirectX SDK (June 2010)\Include\xnamath.h  160
Error   36  error C4430: missing type specifier - int assumed. Note: C++ does not support default-int   C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft DirectX SDK (June 2010)\Include\xnamath.h  160
Error   41  error C4430: missing type specifier - int assumed. Note: C++ does not support default-int   C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft DirectX SDK (June 2010)\Include\xnamath.h  217
Error   42  error C4430: missing type specifier - int assumed. Note: C++ does not support default-int   C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft DirectX SDK (June 2010)\Include\xnamath.h  217
Error   44  error C4430: missing type specifier - int assumed. Note: C++ does not support default-int   C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft DirectX SDK (June 2010)\Include\xnamath.h  246
Error   45  error C4430: missing type specifier - int assumed. Note: C++ does not support default-int   C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft DirectX SDK (June 2010)\Include\xnamath.h  246
Error   47  error C4430: missing type specifier - int assumed. Note: C++ does not support default-int   C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft DirectX SDK (June 2010)\Include\xnamath.h  260
Error   48  error C4430: missing type specifier - int assumed. Note: C++ does not support default-int   C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft DirectX SDK (June 2010)\Include\xnamath.h  260
Error   61  error C4430: missing type specifier - int assumed. Note: C++ does not support default-int   C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft DirectX SDK (June 2010)\Include\xnamath.h  342
Error   62  error C4430: missing type specifier - int assumed. Note: C++ does not support default-int   C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft DirectX SDK (June 2010)\Include\xnamath.h  342
Error   63  error C4430: missing type specifier - int assumed. Note: C++ does not support default-int   C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft DirectX SDK (June 2010)\Include\xnamath.h  342
Error   64  error C4430: missing type specifier - int assumed. Note: C++ does not support default-int   C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft DirectX SDK (June 2010)\Include\xnamath.h  342
Error   65  error C4430: missing type specifier - int assumed. Note: C++ does not support default-int   C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft DirectX SDK (June 2010)\Include\xnamath.h  342
Error   67  error C4430: missing type specifier - int assumed. Note: C++ does not support default-int   C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft DirectX SDK (June 2010)\Include\xnamath.h  343
Error   68  error C4430: missing type specifier - int assumed. Note: C++ does not support default-int   C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft DirectX SDK (June 2010)\Include\xnamath.h  343
Error   69  error C4430: missing type specifier - int assumed. Note: C++ does not support default-int   C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft DirectX SDK (June 2010)\Include\xnamath.h  343
Error   70  error C4430: missing type specifier - int assumed. Note: C++ does not support default-int   C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft DirectX SDK (June 2010)\Include\xnamath.h  343
Error   71  error C4430: missing type specifier - int assumed. Note: C++ does not support default-int   C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft DirectX SDK (June 2010)\Include\xnamath.h  343
Error   73  error C4430: missing type specifier - int assumed. Note: C++ does not support default-int   C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft DirectX SDK (June 2010)\Include\xnamath.h  344
Error   74  error C4430: missing type specifier - int assumed. Note: C++ does not support default-int   C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft DirectX SDK (June 2010)\Include\xnamath.h  344
Error   75  error C4430: missing type specifier - int assumed. Note: C++ does not support default-int   C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft DirectX SDK (June 2010)\Include\xnamath.h  344
Error   76  error C4430: missing type specifier - int assumed. Note: C++ does not support default-int   C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft DirectX SDK (June 2010)\Include\xnamath.h  344
Error   77  error C4430: missing type specifier - int assumed. Note: C++ does not support default-int   C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft DirectX SDK (June 2010)\Include\xnamath.h  344
Error   79  error C4430: missing type specifier - int assumed. Note: C++ does not support default-int   C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft DirectX SDK (June 2010)\Include\xnamath.h  345
Error   80  error C4430: missing type specifier - int assumed. Note: C++ does not support default-int   C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft DirectX SDK (June 2010)\Include\xnamath.h  345
Error   81  error C4430: missing type specifier - int assumed. Note: C++ does not support default-int   C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft DirectX SDK (June 2010)\Include\xnamath.h  345
Error   82  error C4430: missing type specifier - int assumed. Note: C++ does not support default-int   C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft DirectX SDK (June 2010)\Include\xnamath.h  345
Error   83  error C4430: missing type specifier - int assumed. Note: C++ does not support default-int   C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft DirectX SDK (June 2010)\Include\xnamath.h  345
Error   85  error C4430: missing type specifier - int assumed. Note: C++ does not support default-int   C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft DirectX SDK (June 2010)\Include\xnamath.h  347
Error   86  error C4430: missing type specifier - int assumed. Note: C++ does not support default-int   C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft DirectX SDK (June 2010)\Include\xnamath.h  347
Error   92  error C4430: missing type specifier - int assumed. Note: C++ does not support default-int   C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft DirectX SDK (June 2010)\Include\xnamath.h  360
Error   96  error C4430: missing type specifier - int assumed. Note: C++ does not support default-int   C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft DirectX SDK (June 2010)\Include\xnamath.h  360
Error   98  error C4430: missing type specifier - int assumed. Note: C++ does not support default-int   C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft DirectX SDK (June 2010)\Include\xnamath.h  361
Error   101 error C4430: missing type specifier - int assumed. Note: C++ does not support default-int   C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft DirectX SDK (June 2010)\Include\xnamath.h  361
Error   109 error C4430: missing type specifier - int assumed. Note: C++ does not support default-int   C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft DirectX SDK (June 2010)\Include\xnamath.h  363
Error   122 error C4430: missing type specifier - int assumed. Note: C++ does not support default-int   C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft DirectX SDK (June 2010)\Include\xnamath.h  378
Error   124 error C4430: missing type specifier - int assumed. Note: C++ does not support default-int   C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft DirectX SDK (June 2010)\Include\xnamath.h  378
Error   127 error C4430: missing type specifier - int assumed. Note: C++ does not support default-int   C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft DirectX SDK (June 2010)\Include\xnamath.h  386
Error   128 error C4430: missing type specifier - int assumed. Note: C++ does not support default-int   C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft DirectX SDK (June 2010)\Include\xnamath.h  386
Error   130 error C4430: missing type specifier - int assumed. Note: C++ does not support default-int   C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft DirectX SDK (June 2010)\Include\xnamath.h  391
Error   131 error C4430: missing type specifier - int assumed. Note: C++ does not support default-int   C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft DirectX SDK (June 2010)\Include\xnamath.h  391
Error   133 error C4430: missing type specifier - int assumed. Note: C++ does not support default-int   C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft DirectX SDK (June 2010)\Include\xnamath.h  392
Error   134 error C4430: missing type specifier - int assumed. Note: C++ does not support default-int   C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft DirectX SDK (June 2010)\Include\xnamath.h  392
Error   155 error C4430: missing type specifier - int assumed. Note: C++ does not support default-int   C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft DirectX SDK (June 2010)\Include\xnamath.h  423
Error   156 error C4430: missing type specifier - int assumed. Note: C++ does not support default-int   C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft DirectX SDK (June 2010)\Include\xnamath.h  423
Error   158 error C4430: missing type specifier - int assumed. Note: C++ does not support default-int   C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft DirectX SDK (June 2010)\Include\xnamath.h  424
Error   159 error C4430: missing type specifier - int assumed. Note: C++ does not support default-int   C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft DirectX SDK (June 2010)\Include\xnamath.h  424
    178 IntelliSense: expected a ')'    d:\d3d11normalmap\d3d11normalmap\randomvariables.h  40
    179 IntelliSense: expected a declaration    d:\d3d11normalmap\d3d11normalmap\randomvariables.h  40
    177 IntelliSense: expected an identifier    d:\d3d11normalmap\d3d11normalmap\randomvariables.h  40
    176 IntelliSense: no suitable constructor exists to convert from "XMVECTOR (FLOAT x, FLOAT y, FLOAT z, FLOAT w)" to "__m128"    d:\d3d11normalmap\d3d11normalmap\randomvariables.h  40
    174 IntelliSense: the #endif for this directive is missing  d:\d3d11normalmap\d3d11normalmap\randomvariables.h  3
    175 IntelliSense: this declaration has no storage class or type specifier   d:\d3d11normalmap\d3d11normalmap\randomvariables.h  34
```

Comment: i have other externs like this and they work perfectly fine hence why im confused

Comment: can you define "not working"?

Comment: unable to complie, a ton of xnamath errors come up when i moved the class object declaration to the model.cpp

http://i.imgur.com/nFXXvW1.png

Comment: Hard to help without the errors !

Comment: You might want look at this: http://stackoverflow.com/a/10422050/4342498

Comment: Don't use global variables.

Comment: @NathanOliver thats essentially what i've done except i've included the header containing the class information and declared the extern. and the corresponding cpp file for the class contains the declaration of the class object.

Comment: removing #endif will result in redeclaration of the class.

@NeilKirk am re-writing a tutorial code to learn directX11, currently moving all into classes etc eventually they'll all be gone but i dont know enough about dx to re-write from scratch