# Decluttering code - Hiding helper functions in a different file

Tags: c, header, refactoring, structure

I have a scenario.c file that defines the some functions like below:

Static Functions:

`scenario_config()`, `scenario_start()`, `scenario_stop()`, `scenario_close()`

Structure (only thing) Visible to Parent Src/Header files:

```
struct scenario_struct = {.config = scenario_config, .start = scenario_start, .stop = scenario_stop, .close = scenario_close}
```

Also, there is a `scenario.h` header file that declares a ton of `#define`s and such that is included in the parent header file too.

Now coming to my question: There is a set of static helper functions and static constants and `#define`s in this `scenario.c` file that I want to put in a different file, to reduce clutter. I would be making them non-static to do so. But, they are only used in this file, so putting them in `scenario.h` makes it visible to its parent as well. I thought of a second header, but dont think I can put the static constants in there. What is the best way to do this?

Comment: You cannot put static functions into a different .c file

Comment: maybe you could put your static functions in a separate file like `static_functions.c` file, then `#include "static_functions.c"` in `scenario.c`,, but I don't know I've never tried anything like that.

Comment: If the helper static functions and static constants are meant to be used only in the file 'scenerio.c' file, then what is the need to  put them into a different file?

Comment: Okay, I was planning on making the functions and constants non static if I move them to a different file.

The main intention of doing this was to reduce clutter as the helper functions grew a lot and made it difficult to just go through the basic static functions. I would like some tips on whether this is a good idea, or a terribly bad one. It makes the code easier to read, but is another layer of abstraction.

Comment: Are you confusing "file" with "compilation unit"? You can `#include` another C file, it is part of the same unit. It need not appear in the makefile.

Answer (score 0):

As mentioned by Michael in the comments, you can't move the static functions into another file.

Also see: [How to call the static function from another c file?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35425790/how-to-call-the-static-function-from-another-c-file)