# How to use global variables in C functions included in other files

Tags: c

I have a simple program like:

```
int velocity=0;

#include "extra.h"

int main()
{
    extra();
    return 0;
}
```

where `extra.h` is:

```
void extra(){
   velocity += 1;
}
```

yet when I compile this, I get the error:

```
extra.h:5:5: error: 'velocity' was not declared in this scope
```

Obviously, my code in `extra.h` can't "see" the variables in main.c, but why is this? How do I fix this?

Comment: Try putting the velocity variable in the .h file instead.

Comment: @uvr That is certainly not a good practice.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10422034/when-to-use-extern-in-c

Comment: @OP: Why do you _define_ a function in a header, in first place?

Comment: What compiler are you using? This worked as is with clang 3.4.

Comment: @RobertPrévost, gcc

Answer (score 0):

You could add the following declaration to `extra.h`:

```
extern int velocity;
```

---

However, `extra()` shouldn't be defined in `extra.h` in the first place. This will cause problems if `extra.h` is included by multiple `.c` files in the same binary. The following is what you should have:

`extra.h`:

```
void extra();
```

`extra.c`:

```
#include "extra.h"

static int velocity = 0;

void extra() {
   velocity += 1;
}
```

`main.c`:

```
#include "extra.h"

int main()
{
    extra();
    return 0;
}
```