# C++ Include guards

Tags: c++, include-guards

I know this been asked a number of times but no answers seem to solve this.

I have two files.

Main.cpp

```
#include <irrlicht\irrlicht.h>

#include <vector>
#include <string> 
#include <iostream>

#include "Scene.h"
#include "Camera.h"
#include "Gui.h"

irr::IrrlichtDevice* device;
irr::video::IVideoDriver* driver;

int main() {
 device = irr::createDevice(irr::video::EDT_SOFTWARE, irr::core::dimension2d<irr::u32>(640, 480), 16, false, false, false, 0);

if (!device)
    return 1;

device->setWindowCaption(L"NeoTrap");
driver = device->getVideoDriver();
sceneManager = device->getSceneManager();
GUIEnvironment = device->getGUIEnvironment();

//Testing
Mesh* ground = new Mesh();
//Testing

while (device->run()) {
    driver->beginScene(true, true, irr::video::SColor(255, 120, 102, 136));

    sceneManager->drawAll();
    GUIEnvironment->drawAll();

    driver->endScene();
}

device->drop();
return 0;
}
```

Scene.h

```
#ifndef _SCENE_HEADER_
#define _SCENE_HEADER_

irr::scene::ISceneManager* sceneManager; 

struct Mesh {
public:
Mesh();

private:
};

class Scene {
public:
Scene();

private:

};

#endif
```

What I am trying to do is declared a variable in Scene.h and define it from within the main function. I am not sure if I don't understand include guards, but I am getting weird errors:

'irr': is not a class or namespace name
syntax error: missing ';' before '*'
missing type specifier - int assumed. Note: C++ does not support default-int

but when I move the following line back in the Main.cpp file

```
irr::scene::ISceneManager* sceneManager;
```

the program compile. When am I not able to declare it in scene.h and set the value from the main function?

Comment: In which file is `irr::scene::ISceneManager` defined?

Comment: Scene.h, at the very top.

Comment: No, that's where you're declaring a variable of pointer-to-that-type.  Where is that **type** (class or struct) defined?

Comment: @Kurieita Where is class `ISceneManager` declared?

Comment: Oh, it is defined in Irrlicht/Irrlichy.h, which is the library I am using.

Comment: This has nothing to do with include guards as far as I can see. Recommend changing the title to something more representative.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It's best to not declare variables in headers. It ends badly far more often than not because every file that includes the header will make their very own `sceneManager`. When the linker comes along to put the program together it may find dozens of `sceneManager`s all with an equal claim to being the real `sceneManager`, throw its hands up in disgust, and spray error messages all over the console.

In scene.h add

```
#include <irrlicht\irrlicht.h>
```

up at the top to declare all the bits and bobs of irrlicht so that they are available in scene.h.

Then change

```
irr::scene::ISceneManager* sceneManager;
```

to

```
extern irr::scene::ISceneManager* sceneManager;
```

`extern` tells the compiler that `sceneManager` exists and storage will be allocated somewhere else. The compiler smiles and carries on, leaving sorting out where the one, true `sceneManager` is to the linker.

Finally, put

```
irr::scene::ISceneManager* sceneManager;
```

in Main.cpp to allocate storage so that the linker has a `sceneManager` to find.

[Documentation on `extern`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/storage_duration)

Recomended reading: [When to use extern in C++](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10422034/when-to-use-extern-in-c)

Comment: Very nice and very fast response. Thanks so much +1 for you. :)

Answer (score 3):

You are declaring that `sceneManager` is of type `irr::scene::ISceneManager*`, but the `irr` namespace doesn't exist when you are declaring that variable. Add an `include` to the header file that declares that namespace before declaring your variable.

After that, you'll need to declare `sceneManager` to be `extern` in the header so that each compilation unit that includes that header doesn't create its own instance of the variable. Then because it is `extern`, you will also want to redeclare it (without `extern`) in main.cpp.