# How use value of variable in another class

Tags: c++, class

Imagine I have a class and it has a private value for example this value name is **`a`**, then I set it's value to 10.

How I can **access** to **this variable** with **its value (10)** in another class?

***(I do not want to use friend function and friend class)***

a.h

```
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;
static int s=0;

/* run this program using the console pauser or add your own getch, system("pause") or input loop */

class a
{
    private:
    public:
        void sets(int );
};
```

a.cpp

```
#include "a.h"

void a::sets(int y){
    cin >> y;
    s=y;
}
```

main.cpp

```
#include"a.h"

int main()
{
    int i=0;
    int q;
    a a1;
    a1.sets(q);
    cout << s+1 << endl;
    for (i=1; i<5; i++){
        if (s == i) cout << "ok";
    }
}
```

Comment: Make a getter function for `a`.

Comment: An answer to this question can be found in any book/tutorial dealing with C++ classes. Please take the time to go through such a book. That will be more helpful for you in the long run than getting an answer to this specific question.

Comment: Why not a pulic member `int get(){return privateMember;}`?

Comment: no its not my mean say code

Comment: Why you use a static global variable (`s`) instead of a private member?

Comment: if i donot use static it get me error multi difinition s

Comment: And the reason for that is every time a.h is included another `s` is defined. The linker doesn't know which which `s` is the real `s`, so it stops and complains. `static` makes a different `s` in every [translation unit](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1106149/what-is-a-translation-unit-in-c) so the linker stops complaining, but now you have different `s`s. To do this right, and you don't need this here, Rama's answer is a better solution, you need to declare `extern int s;` in the header and in one and only one cpp file `int s;` to allocate storage for the single `s`.

Comment: [When to use extern in C++](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10422034/when-to-use-extern-in-c)

Answer (score 0):

If you do not want to use `friend`ship, add a public interface to this variable (setter and/or getter class members).

Comment: its not suitable for me  i have same problem

Answer (score 0):

Either make the variable `public` or add a function to get the value that returns it, like `int getA() const { return a; }` .

Comment: ok i know that , you just print its value i want add this with another value or use it in main

Comment: Proper form would be int GetA() const;

Comment: you just print s value i want work with this value and change it to main

Answer (score 0):

Use a private member `s` in your class `a` instead of a global variable, and access it via public Getter function `GetS`

Example:

```
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;

class a
{
    private:
        int s;

    public:
        void SetS() { cin >> s; }
        int GetS() const { return s; } 
};

int main()
{
    a a1;
    a1.SetS();
    int s1=a1.GetS();
    cout << s1+1 << endl;
    for (int i=1; i<5; i++){
            if (s1 == i) cout << "ok";
    }
}
```