# Creating c++ global variable for a queue

Tags: c++, visual-studio-2017, queue, global-variables, extern

Note: This problem is solved in another post.  The link to that post is included at the bottom.

I'm using Visual Studio 2017 community edition.
I have a queue I want to be a global variable.

My main routine looks like this:

```
#include "TestClass.h"
using namespace std;
extern queue<Message*> g_incoming;

int main()
{
    PFRHelloMessage* msg1 = new PFRHelloMessage( 0, 1, 2, 30, 40, 1500, 45, 17);
    g_incoming.push(msg1);

    DropLinkMessage* msg2 = new DropLinkMessage( 1, 3, 4);
    g_incoming.push(msg2);

    AddLinkMessage* msg3 = new AddLinkMessage( 2, 5, 6);
    g_incoming.push(msg3);

    //while (!g_incoming.empty())
    //{
    //  Message* m = g_incoming.front();
    //  g_incoming.pop();
    //  cout << m->getType() << endl;
    //}

    TestClass* tc = new TestClass();
    tc->dump();

    return 0;
```

TestClass looks like this:

```
#include "TestClass.h"
#include <queue>
#include "Message.h"
extern queue<Message*> g_incoming;
void dump()
{

    cout << "start: externally accessed" << endl;
    //while (!g_incoming.empty())
    //{
    //  Message* m = g_incoming.front();
    //  g_incoming.pop();
    //  cout << m->getType() << endl;
    //}
    cout << "end: externally accessed" << endl;
}
```

The errors I get tell me that I have two unresolved external variables.
(Of course this is not the real program.  I obviously don't need an external variable here.  I need to figure out how this works for the real program.)

Solution:
Each of the comments to this question offers some useful information; however,
I've discovered this is a duplicate question and a link to complete example answer is here:
[When to use extern in C++](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10422034/when-to-use-extern-in-c)
I've implemented this using my own classes and it works.
I'm not sure why I didn't see (or perhaps didn't notice) that result yesterday.

Comment: please post the error message verbatim instead of paraphrasing it in your own words. And please provide a [mcve] (instead of leaving a note that this isnt the real code)

Comment: There is nothing particular  to queue here. You have 2 declarations for a global variable (promising that you have created it somewhere), but no definition (actually creating it). You need to add exactly one definition in only one of your .cpp files.

Comment: As @Frank suggests, removing extern from only one of your .cpp files will do it. I would tend to move the declarations to an appropriate .h file and have a definition  in  the most appropriate .cpp file.

Comment: What I mean by saying "it's not the real" program is that the example is a toy.  It is incomplete, but sufficient for diagnosis, as is evidenced by the fact that several people gave useful information.

Answer (score 1):

I suppose it's a linker problem.
Simply put the definition into a .cpp file (ommitting extern):

```
queue<Message*> g_incoming;
```