# Global Variable not Updating itself - c++

Tags: c++, qt, global-variables, global

This is a simple example of what i am trying to achieve: 
I have a header file GlobalVar.h

```
#ifndef MY_GLOBALS_H
#define MY_GLOBALS_H

extern int flag;

#endif
```

A MainWindow.cpp

```
#include "Globalvar.h"
int flag;
void function() {
qDebug() <<"Flag is"<<flag;
}
```

A main.cpp

```
    #include "GlobalVar.h"
    int flag=0;
    int main() {
    if(true) {
    flag=1;
    qDebug() <<"Flag is"<<flag;
    }
}
```

Now the console output shows the value of flag as : "Flag is 1" (In Line no:61) and "Flag is 0" (In Line no: 80).

This means that the flag has been set to 1 already when it reaches to the MainWindow.cpp then why does to shows the value of flag equal to 0 ?

Comment: How did this link? You have a duplicate definition of `flag`.

Comment: You have two variables named flag. You want to define your extern `int flag;` in one cpp file, not both.

Comment: Also there is no call to `function()` - so how you get 2 outputs is a mystery.

Comment: Earlier I defined flag in main.cpp only but throws error : Error31 error LNK2001: unresolved external symbol "int flag" (?flag@@3HA)

Comment: All the functions are being called from another function. It's a small part of a big project

Comment: Please post a [mcve].  If you post code that either does not compile or can not show you problem you have, how can you expect an answer?

Comment: What was the complete error message including the obj file the unresolved symbol was in?

Comment: I am sorry for some errors in my question : Here is the complete error including the obj file: Error 31 error LNK2001: unresolved external symbol "int flag" (?flag@@3HA) in the  MainWindow.obj file

Comment: aside: Do yourself a favour, and don't do this... global variables are going to lead to pain later; and that later might be sooner than you think

Comment: @UKMonkey I wish i could do that but it is the requirement of the program to use a global variable

Comment: If anyone finds the solution! Do Post it, meanwhile I implemented a workaround using singleton class. [link](https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/singleton-class-java/) provides a beautiful insight about singleton classes. I advise anyone who comes here to have a look on it. Thanks! :-)

Answer (score 2):

You *declare* the global variable flag in MY_GLOBALS_H:

```
extern int flag;
```

You then *define* it in MainWindow.cpp:

```
int flag; // this essentially means "int flag = 0;"
```

And then you define it again in main.cpp:

```
int flag = 0;
```

You can declare a variable many times but it must be defined exactly once.

Comment: Here's a reference to this question which has been answered previously:
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10422034/when-to-use-extern-in-c

Comment: I am sorry but you are wrong. I had to define the flag in MainWindow.cpp because it threw error elsewise (error is given in the comments to the question).  I ran a similar program in Qt Creator WITHOUT defining flag in MainWindow.cpp and again I got the same output "flag is 0" from MainWindow and "flag is 1" from main

Comment: @jmoriarty You have definitions `int flag;` in MainWindow.cpp and `int flag=0;` in main.cpp. i.e _Two_ definitions. One of them doesn't belong. Take one out.

Comment: I was addressing any linker errors you were experiencing. The only way this program of yours even links is if one of those "int flag;" definitions was made inside a different scope (i.e. within a namespace). Otherwise, you will get a "duplicate symbol" error. This would also explain how the values don't sync up because you essentially have 2 distinct variables.

Comment: I get the duplicate symbol error when compiling it with Qt Creator but the output still doesnt matches even after removing the definition and compiling it in Qt Creator where as in VS it throws Link error on removing the definition from MainWindow

Comment: If anyone finds the solution! Do Post it, meanwhile I implemented a workaround using singleton class. [link](https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/singleton-class-java/) provides a beautiful insight about singleton classes. I advise anyone who comes here to have a look on it. Thanks! :-)