# Error: redefinition of "a static variable" in C header files

Tags: c, variables, static, header-files, static-initialization

I have some static variables (say, var1 and var2) declared in two different files. The variables have same name in both files. Some variables (say var1) are not initialized in their declaration and some are (var2), like following.

**file1.h**

```
static bool var1;
static bool var2 = false;
```

**file2.h**

```
static bool var1;
static bool var2 = false;
```

According to my understanding, static variables are only restricted to the c files(or h files) they're declared in, so I should be safe having same variable names in multiple header files. But when I compile code, I get error "redefinition of var2", only for the variables that have been initialized.

1. Why this error occurs only for var2 ?
2. Is my implementation alright ?

**Edit:**
since some mentioned to use extern keyword, I'd like to clarify that both var1 and var2 are supposed to have different values in different c files, and should only be restricted to their respective files,

Comment: Header files are copied into `.c` files. If you include both headers into the same file, you will have multiple definitions.

Comment: There is only a *tentative* definition for `var1`.

Comment: use `extern`  in the header file: [When to use extern in C++](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10422034/when-to-use-extern-in-c)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No.  The multiple declaration of `var1` is okay, but the multiple *definition* of `var2` is not.  You can't initialize a variable twice...even if the values are the same.

I solve problems like this using preprocessor guards, such as:

```
#if !defined(MY_APP__VARS_DEFINED)
static int var1, var2=0;
#define MY_APP__VARS_DEFINED
#endif
```

Even then, I don't recommend duplicating the definitions in multiple header files.  It's a maintenance problem.  Sooner or later, someone is likely to change that initial value in one header and not find all other headers it's defined in.  It also makes renaming ("refactoring") harder.  (...and violates the [DRY Principle](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Don%27t_repeat_yourself).)

You might want to rethink your design, though.  Global variables usually lead to brittle applications; harder to maintain and easy to break.

Comment: actually these variables are supposed to hold different values in different c files, but since the information is almost similar I named them same, they're supposed to be global inside one c file, but should not be global to the whole program, isn't that's why static keyword used for ? just like we use same name local variables in multiple functions(e.g., 'i' in for loops), I want same global variables in multiple compilation unit, is it possible ?

Comment: @Salman Yes, it's possible.  Just use the preprocessor guard idea as shown.  It's probably a good idea to initialize *all* such variables; giving a recognizable nonsense value (like 0xDEADDEAD or some such) for "non-initialized" variables.  I'd still put the declarations in common header file that other headers can include if they need to.  Single point of maintenance, DRY, one place to put comments that generate developer docs, etc.

Answer (score 0):

*Why this error occurs only for var2 ?* if you include `file1.h` and `file2.h` in same source file `test.cpp` then `var2` will be having two definition and compiler is unable to choose which one to take and throws the error.

To avoid this declare `var2` as a `extern` in header `.h` file and define in respective source `.cpp` file.

While in case of `var1` it's just `declaration` not `definition` so it won't throws the error i.e multiple declaration is possible.

Also the `static` declaration like

```
static bool var1;
```

means that the variabe `var1` is  visible only in the current compilation unit.

Side note, `static` variable having internal linkage i.e it  hides `static` variable  from other translation units. Though `static` variables  can be `defined` in multiple translation units.

And  `extern` variable having  external linkage, i.e  `extern` variable will be visible to other translation units, but the `extern` variable  should be define only in one translation unit.

Comment: actually these variables are supposed to hold different values in different c files, but since the information is almost similar I named them same, they're supposed to be global inside one c file, but should not be global to the whole program, isn't that's why static keyword used for ? just like we use same name local variables in multiple functions(e.g., 'i' in for loops), I want same global variables in multiple compilation unit, is it possible ?

Answer (score 0):

If a source file is including both file1.h and file2.h, it will have multiple definitions of `var2`.  That's what causing the error.

Rather than declaring / defining these static variables in header files, put them directly the necessary C source files.  That way you won't have to deal with multiple definitions.