# How to create global variable in c++ that can access multiple files

Tags: c#, c++

I used following code to provide a global variable.

```
namespace STR.Pref
{
    public static class Pref
    {
        public static Lang PrimaryLang { get; set; } = Lang.Sinhala;
        public static bool InsTrans { get; set; } = true;
        public static HotKey Key { get; set; } = new HotKey();
    }
}
```

So I can use following code to assign value to that global variable (any file).(without instantiating)

```
    private static void SetValue(Pref_tempObj tempObj)
    {
        Pref.Pref.Key = tempObj.Key;
        Pref.Pref.InsTrans = tempObj.InsTrans;
        Pref.Pref.PrimaryLang = tempObj.PrimaryLang;
   }
```

The program works perfectly,But recently I was interested in c++ so I made a decision to write that program in c++/clr with the small update. I'm bit new to c++ and I don't understand how can I accomplish this using c++.(whether using pointer or something else)

Answer (score 1):

Ok, I really not recommend that but you can do following this instructions.

On a `Global.h` file (I mean a header will be include on every .cpp)

`extern MyType MyTypeVar;`

Declare on a .cpp

`MyType MyTypeVar`

And on every .cpp that you will include the `Global.h` have access to `MyTypeVar`.

> See:
>
> [When to use extern in C++](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10422034/when-to-use-extern-in-c)
>
> [Extern](https://learn.microsoft.com/pt-br/cpp/cpp/extern-cpp?view=vs-2017)
>
> [What is the function of extern](http://www.cplusplus.com/forum/general/21368/)

Comment: But linker error: MyTypeVar already defined (and I already tried)

Comment: Have you declared on a .cpp with the .h correctly? See this link: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10422034/when-to-use-extern-in-c here have a better code sample