# Should I add keyword `extern` to the definition of a constant to share among source files?

Tags: c++, constants, extern

In "C++ Primer, Fifth Edition" on page 95. Talking about constants. He said:

> Sometimes we have a `const` variable that we want to share across multiple files but whose initializer is not a constant expression. In this case, we don’t want the compiler to generate a separate variable in each file. Instead, we want the `const` object to behave like other (non `const`) variables. We want to define the `const` in one file, and declare it in the other files that use that object.
>
> To define a single instance of a `const` variable, we use the keyword `extern` on both its definition and declaration(s):
>
> `// file_1.cc` defines and initializes a `const` that is accessible to other files.
>
> `extern const int bufSize = fcn();`
>
> `// file_1.h`
>
> `extern const int bufSize; // same bufSize as defined in file_1.cc`

What I am not sure of is the last paragraph; I removed `extern` from the definition of `bufsize` but it is ok and is accessible from other files?!

```
const int bufSize = fcn(); // without keyword extern
```

Why he said we should add keyword `extern` to both declarations and definition of `bufsize` to be accessible from other files but `extern` as I guess is enough in declarations?

Thank you for your help.

Comment: Let me know if this answer your question and I (or somebody) will close as a duplicate: [When to use extern in C++](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10422034/when-to-use-extern-in-c)

Comment: @user4581301: I know the usage of const and extern but what matters me `extern` in definition which I see redundant.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You are correct that `extern` is not needed in cpp file.

First, you need to understand what is a declaration and a definition. Your `bufSize` needs a declaration in every translation unit it is used, and a single definition inside your program. So let's look at what you have in the .h file:

```
extern const int bufSize;
```

This is a valid declaration of `const int` variable. No confusion here.

Now you need a definition, which goes to a .cpp file, and you need to make sure that this exists in a single place in the whole program, otherwise you are breaking ODR - One Definition Rule. This is what you currently have:

```
extern const int bufSize = fcn();
```

This is a valid definition, since any declaration with extern storage class and initializer is a definition. However,

```
const int bufSize = fcn();
```

Also is a definition. And with preceeding declaration of `extern`, this definition has an external linkage - which means, it can be accessed from other translation units (without that, `const int bufSize` in namespace scope would have internal linkage).

Bottom line - `extern` in the example doesn't affect the compiler behavior, but reminds whoever is reading the code that the variable has external linkage (as it is not immediately obvious from this line).

Further reading:

https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/definition

https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/storage_duration