# c++: "Redeclare" extern namespace variables in .cpp

Tags: c++, windows, visual-studio, namespaces

I'm new with c++ and came across to this code:

**File.h**

```
namespace Type
{
   typedef BOOL (WINAPI *TYCopyFile)
   (
    PCHAR lpExistingFileName,
    PCHAR lpNewFileName,
    BOOL  bFailIfExists
   );
}

namespace Func
{
  extern Types::TYCopyFile pCopyFileA;
}
```

**File.cpp**

```
namespace Funcs
{
  Types::TYCopyFile pCopyFileA;
}

void Init
{
  Funcs::pCopyFileA = (Types::T_CopyFile) GetProcAddress(hKernel32, "CopyFileA");
}
```

The idea is real simple. I have namespace of `typedef`(`Types`) and create function pointer in another namespace(`Funcs`) as extern. Then I define that function pointer in `File.cpp` in `Init` function.

The question that I have is that why do I need to redeclare `namespace Funcs` in `File.cpp`? Why can't I just have `Init` function which would initialize `Funcs::pCopyFileA`? As I understand `extern`, it tells compiler that the variable exists somewhere and tell linker to find it. Why can't linker find it without `namespace Funcs` in `File.cpp`?

Comment: When you use `extern` you promise to define the variable in one of your translation units. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10422034/when-to-use-extern-in-c

Comment: and I define them in `void Init` function, why do I need `namespace Funcs` in `File.cpp`?

Comment: That's not a definition, it's an assignment. (This works the same as if it were in the global namespace, by the way.)

Comment: You aren't defining it in the function. You're assigning to it.

Comment: If you did define it in a function is a variable local to that function. once Init ends it would no longer exist.

Comment: The actual variable name you promise to defined is Funcs::pCopyFileA the namespace is part of the naming

Comment: understood. Thanks to all of you :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For all symbols in C++ you need both a *declaration* and a *definition*. The header file contains the declaration of `Func::pCopyFileA`, the source file contains the definition.

If you define the variable in the header file (i.e. you remove the `extern` keyword) then the definition would be done in all [*translation units*](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Translation_unit_(programming)) that include the header file. This breaks the [one definition rule](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/definition#One_Definition_Rule), and would lead to multiple-definition errors when linking.

Comment: Although they could use `inline` if they have C++17 so they can define and declare it in the header file.

Comment: so without `extern` I redefine same variable multiple times right?

Comment: @user3503143 Yes that's correct. Adding the `extern` keyword makes it a declaration instead of a definition. And you can declare a variable how many times you want (as long as you declare it the same way).