# How to access a variable from .cpp file in a .h file

Tags: c++, variables, header-files

Consider this scenario:

*File1.cpp*:

```
double dir = M_PI/2;
```

*hFile1.h*:

```
void printdir () {
cout << dir;
}
```

*Main.cpp*:

```
#include "hFile1.h"
int main () {
printdir();
}
```

This obviously will not work because hFile1.h will throw an error: "use of undeclared identifier 'dir'". In this example, I want to be able to access and use the defined **dir** variable in hFile1.h. Is this possible?

NOTE: I have already tried using **extern** based on similar posts on this topic and it didn't work, even after I did exactly what they did. Code:

*File1.cpp*:

```
extern double dir = M_PI/2;
```

*hFile1.h*:

```
extern double dir;
void printdir () {
cout << dir;
}
```

*Main.cpp*:

```
#include "hFile1.h"
int main () {
printdir();
}
```

Comment: ```#include "hFile1.h"
#include "File1.cpp"```

Comment: @asmmo Including `.cpp` files is _usually_ a very bad idea.

Comment: I didn't think that you could include .cpp files. Can you?

Comment: @HyperTextMarkupMan `#include` is just a dumb copy and paste of a file's contents, you can include any text file. Doesn't mean you should, though.

Comment: @EtiennedeMartel usually .cpp files don't contain var declaration.

Comment: @EtiennedeMartel Why shouldn't you include a cpp file?

Comment: @HyperTextMarkupMan `I have already tried using extern ... and it didn't work` Post *that* code, then. All you need is an `extern double dir;` declaration in either `hFile1.h` or `main.cpp`.

Comment: @HyperTextMarkupMan Because then you risk ending up with multiple definitions.

Comment: @dxiv You are correct and that is exactly what I did but I found that the value did not change in main when I changed it in File1.cpp

Comment: Did you just forget to rebuild your program?

Comment: @HyperTextMarkupMan Then you did something other than you say you did. That's why posting the actual code matters.

Comment: @EtiennedeMartel I did build my program but the value displayed was the old value not the changed value.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [When to use extern in C++](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10422034/when-to-use-extern-in-c)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to use keyword "extern" in `hFile1.h` as below. I tested, it worked.

```
extern double dir;

void printdir () {
    cout << dir;
}
```

Comment: What I don't understand is what the extern type is *doing* in this scenario.

Comment: @HyperTextMarkupMan It's to mark `dir` has having _external linkage_. [See this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1358400/what-is-external-linkage-and-internal-linkage) for more details.