# How to define a constant in a main and use it in other header files?

Tags: c++, arduino, header, arduino-c++

**file0: Main.ino (it's arduino file):**

```
#define AXIS_SERIAL Serial1
#include "header.h"
...
void setup(){...}
void loop() {...}
...
```

**file1: header.h**

```
...
#ifndef AXIS_SERIAL
#define AXIS_SERIAL Serial
#endif
...
```

**file2: header.cpp**

```
...
AXIS_SERIAL.print("Hello World")
...
```

**Question:**
When I use function in header.cpp value inside of AXIS_SERIAL is still Serial (not Serial1).
Is there a way to define a constant in main file, and use it in other header file(s)? If so, it will going to generalize my piece of code.

I do know that it's possible to declare a variable something like `HardwareSerial Axis_serial = Serial1;` but I may use Software Serial in the future. So I need a thing that works both Hardware & Software Serial classes.

Comment: Have you looked at: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10422034/when-to-use-extern-in-c ?

Comment: @ProgrammingRage, it is a preprocessor macro

Comment: the header.cpp is a separate translation unit in which the define you have in ino isn't applied. https://forum.arduino.cc/index.php?topic=721040.msg4847132#msg4847132

Answer (score -1):

Yes, that should be possible, in the end the #define directive replaces your new "alias" with the string that you entered:

```cpp
#define MY_DEFINE Serial
```

your code

```cpp
void loop(){
   MY_DEFINE.println("Hello World!");
}
```

what your compiler sees:

```cpp
void loop(){
   Serial.println("Hello World!");
}
```

Comment: Yes, In main.ino file,
AXIS_SERIAL is Serial1. 
However, when I use functions declared in header.cpp (which uses AXIS_SERIAL) AXIS_SERIAL is still Serial (not Serial1).

Comment: this is a wrong answer