# How to share a global variable between files using header file?

Tags: c++, qt, class, variables, global-variables

I have a header file and 3 cpp files. I want to share an array object between my files to store data in it and use it (global variable).

My header file code : info.h

```
#ifndef INFO_H
#define INFO_H
#include "QString"
class ib
{
public:
    QString from,to,seat[32],driver;
}extern o[10];
#endif // INFO_H
```

and my cpp files code :
bilit.cpp

```
#include "info.h"
void bilit::on_pushButton_clicked()
{
    const int f = ui->bnspin->value();
    const int s = ui->stspin->value();
    o[f].seat[s] = ui->pnbtn->text();
}
```

make.cpp

```
#include "info.h"
void make::on_pushButton_clicked()
{
    const int f = ui->spinBox->value();
    o[f].driver = ui->drvbtn->text();
    o[f].to = ui->tobtn->text();
    o[f].from = ui->frombtn->text();
}
```

check.cpp

```
#include "info.h"
void check::on_pushButton_clicked()
{
    const int f = ui->spinBox->value();
    const int s = ui->spinBox_2->value();
    ui->label->setText(o[f].seat[s]);
}
```

and this is my error :
[error](https://i.stack.imgur.com/bNJeZ.jpg)

even i write extern in my cpp files but i get error again :
[error2](https://i.stack.imgur.com/lpvd0.jpg)

any idea how to fix it ? or other way to share a global variable between my files ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Declaring an object as extern can be done many times. All it means is "this object's linkage data is somewhere else".

Your code doesn't contain the "somewhere else" definition.

file.h:

```
extern int i; // i is defined somewhere else
```

file.cpp:

```
int i = 0; // this is the definition
```

some-other-file.cpp:

```
extern int i; // will use the same i in file.cpp
              // alternatively, to avoid duplicating the extern declaration,
              // you can just include file.h
```

To summarize, in one of your cpp files, you need to add:

```
ib o[10];
```

Answer (score 1):

if you use `extern` you need to have definition somewhere in one of your cpp files. Check [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10422034/when-to-use-extern-in-c) for more info.

I think if you change your files like this:

```
#ifndef INFO_H
#define INFO_H
#include "QString"
class ib
{
public:
    QString from,to,seat[32],driver;
};

extern ib o[10];
#endif
```

```
#include "info.h"

ib o[10]; // <-- here we define object that will be extern-ed.

void bilit::on_pushButton_clicked()
{
    const int f = ui->bnspin->value();
    const int s = ui->stspin->value();
    o[f].seat[s] = ui->pnbtn->text();
}
```

it will solve problem.