# linking two cpp files whilst using a struct from a header file

Tags: c++, header

I'm having an issue where I am trying to use variables stored in a struct called from a header file. I am able to call to each cpp file ie., call an action from one to another however variables are proving difficult.

Client.cpp

```cpp
#include <iostream>
#include "Header.h"
#include <vector>;
#include <conio.h>;
#include <string>;

using namespace std;

int main()
{
    cout << "Please enter a name: " << flush;
    cin >> sNam.sNames;

    main2();

    return 0;
}
```

Admin.cpp

```cpp
#include <iostream>
#include "Header.h"
#include <vector>;
#include <conio.h>;
#include <string>;

using namespace std;

void main2()
{
    if (sNam.sNames == sNam1.sNames1)
    {
        cout << "Correct Entry...\n";
    }
    else if (sNam.sNames != sNam1.sNames1)
    {
        cout << "Incorrect Entry...\n";
    }

}
```

Header.h

```cpp
#pragma once
#include "Admin.cpp"
#include "Client.cpp"

struct Names
{
    string sNames;
    string sNames1 = "John";

}sNam, sNam1;
```

Comment: Don't include *.cpp files. The header doesn't even need to know about those files. It's a one way street where the *.cpp files need to know about the header and [amost never] vice versa. I would also choose a better name than `main2()` for the function you call. Something actually descriptive.

Comment: cpp files include header files not the other way around.
So client.cpp and admin.cpp are correct. Remove the .cpp includes from header.h and you should be fine

Comment: Note: Once you stop including the cpp file, you'll have a problem with multiple definitions as Header.h fully defines variables and both cpp files include the header. See [When to use extern in C++](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10422034/when-to-use-extern-in-c) for details and a solution.

Comment: Minor point: `std::cout` and `std::cin` are tied together, so you don't need to flush `std::cout` after a prompt. Reading from `std::cin` will flush `std::cout`.

Answer (score 0):

don't include `cpp` files
also `sNam` and `sNam1` are defined in both `cpp` files, you will have link time error
include `Header.h` in both `Client.cpp` and `Admin.cpp`
then declare what's common in `Header.h`

```
#pragma once
// #include "Admin.cpp"
// #include "Client.cpp"

struct Names
{
    string sNames;
    string sNames1 = "John";
};

extern Names sNam, sNam1;

void main2();
```

in one of `cpp` files

```
#include "Header.h"

Names sNam, sNam1;
```