# Can I extern the entire namespace?

Tags: c++, linker, extern, linkage

Is there a method to declare a namespace with the extern modifier so that the namespace's entire content is externally linked?

Comment: All namespace scoped declarations are externally linked.

Comment: That is not the way the `extern` keyword works, take a look at https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10422034/when-to-use-extern-in-c. In C++ everything is linkable by default, the `static` keyword turn a variable or class as file local.

Comment: @StoryTeller-UnslanderMonica Using e.g. `namespace foo { int a; }` in a header file, and including that header file into multiple source files, will cause the `foo::a` variable to be defined in each translation unit. This is solved by turning the definitions into declarations, by doing `namespace foo { extern int a; }`. But if there's many variables in the namespace `foo` the OP wants to do something like `extern namespace foo { ... }` to make all variables in the namespace `extern` (I guess).

Comment: @Physician Unfortunately it's not possible to make a whole namespace `extern`. You must declare all variables inside it separately.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You seem to be asking two questions. One regarding external linkage and one regarding the `extern` specifier.

---

Regarding the linkage, there is not really a need for such a syntax.

External linkage is already the default at namespace scope, whether in the global namespace or another namespace, except for `const` non-template non-inline variables and members of anonymous unions. (https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/storage_duration#internal_linkage)

So the other way around, syntax to make all names in a namespace have internal linkage, is more likely to be required and this is possible with unnamed namespaces

```
namespace {
    //...
}
```

in which all declared names have internal linkage.

---

Regarding the `extern` specifier used to turn a variable definition into just a declaration at namespace scope or to give it external linkage explicitly, I am not aware of any syntax to apply it to a whole namespace. You will have to specify it explicitly on each variable.