# How to make a Windows DLL which both exports and uses a class instance

Tags: c++, windows, visual-studio, dll

File F1.h is

```
enum class E { A, B, C };

template<class E> class X {
public:   X(const E& y) { self.z = y; }
};

__declspec(dllexport) X<E> foo; // Attempt to declare but not instantiate
```

File F1.cpp is

```
#include <F1.h>
__declspec(dllexport) X<E> foo(E.A); // Attempt to instantiate matching .H declaration
```

File F2.cpp is

```
#include <F1.h>

void f()
{
  E z = foo.z; // Attempt to use from declaration without instantiating
}
```

A Visual Studio C++ project P has F1.cpp and F2.cpp.  Building this project gives LNK2005 error that foo in F1.obj is already defined in F2.obj.

Is there a way to set this up so that foo is exported in P.DLL from F1.obj and is available in F2.cpp and is not defined in F2.obj?

Comment: What is "self.z = y; " means? There is no self in c++, do you mean "this"?

Comment: And if we're talking `this`, consider using the Member Initializer List to initialize the member instead of in-body assignment of the member.

Comment: I think you may be looking for [the `extern` keyword](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10422034/when-to-use-extern-in-c), but my Windows is shaky so I'm not sure on what extra syntax might be needed with a DLL.

Comment: @user4581301 Yeah, adding `extern` to the declaration in the header should do the trick, along with having the standard 'conditional' definitions for importing/exporting the DLLs stuffs.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are variables undefined in your example.

Here is a sample:

F1.h

```
#pragma once

#ifdef MYDLL_EXPORTS
#define MYDLL_API __declspec(dllexport)
#else
#define MYDLL_API __declspec(dllimport)
#endif


enum class E { A, B, C };

template<class E> 
class X 
{
public:  
    X(const E& y) { this->Z = y; }
    E Z;
};

extern  MYDLL_API X<E> foo;
 MYDLL_API void f();
```

F1.cpp

```
#include "F1.h"
X<E> foo(E::B);
```

F2.cpp

```
#include<iostream>
#include "F1.h"

void f()
{
    E z = foo.Z;
    std::cout << (int)z;
}
```

And test project
main.cpp

```
#include <iostream>
#include"../F1.h"    

int main()
{
    std::cout <<(int) foo.Z<<std::endl;
    f();
}
```

OutPut

```
1
1
```

Comment: Hi,@Lars Ericson  May I know if you have got any chance to check my answer?