# How can I use variables in multiple files?

Tags: c++, c, static, include, makefile

I want do define a variable in the header and be able to use it in multiple files. 
e.g. have variable `a` defined somewhere and be able to use/change it in both p1.cpp and p2.cpp

Here is an example with 3 simple files of what I'm trying to do.

```
// vars.hpp
#ifndef VARS_HPP
#define VARS_HPP

int a = 1;
float b = 2.2;
void double_vars();

#endif



// vars.cpp
#include "vars.hpp"
void double_vars () {
    a *= 2;
    b *= 2;
}

// vars_main.cpp
#include <cstdio>
#include "vars.hpp"
int main () {
    printf("a: %d; b: %f\n", a, b);
    double_vars();
    printf("a: %d; b: %f\n", a, b);
}
```

now, compiling the above with:

```
g++ -Wall -W -g vars.cpp vars_main.cpp -o vars && ./vars
```

gives me the following errors:

```
/tmp/ccTPXrSe.o:(.data+0x0): multiple definition of `a'
/tmp/ccnc1vof.o:(.data+0x0): first defined here
/tmp/ccTPXrSe.o:(.data+0x4): multiple definition of `b'
/tmp/ccnc1vof.o:(.data+0x4): first defined here
```

can someone explain to me why this happens? I have guards in the header file so as far as I understand it should only be included once so there should not be multiple declarations

Comment: One of the possible duplicates: http://stackoverflow.com/q/3627941/1202636

Answer (score 4):

In the header file, write this:

```
extern int a;
extern float b;
```

This will *declare* the variables.

In one of the CPP files, write this:

```
int a = 1;
float b = 2.2;
```

This will *define* the variables. It does not matter in which CPP file you put the definitions, as long as the variables are defined exactly once.

Answer (score 4):

First off, don't do this. Global mutable state is usually a bad thing.

The problem is that once the linker finishes combining the files in your include statments, it has seen this twice, once in main.cpp and once in vars_main.cpp:

```
int a = 1;
float b = 2.2;
```

If you only put this in the header file, it shows up in multiple translation units, once for each `cpp` file that includes your header. It's impossible for the compiler to know which a and b you're talking about.

The way to fix this is to declare them `extern` in the header:

```
extern int a;
extern float b;
```

This tells the compiler that a and b are *defined* somewhere, not necessarily in this part of the code.

Then, in one of your cpp files you would define them:

```
int a = 1;
float b = 2.2;
```

That way, there's one well-defined place for the storage for `a` and `b` to live, and the compiler can connect the dots properly.

Answer (score 1):

Collin already described the problem and the solution, but I want to emphasize just how bad a style this is.

As you've found out even from this simple exercise, using globals in this manner is often a Bad Thing.  Aside from the compiler issues you've already found, sharing state between functions using globals causes the following problems:

- it makes the function itself harder to reuse in other programs, because the function is expecting the presence of those symbols;
- changes to one function may cause problems in other functions that share that state (i.e., the changes are not localized to the function);
- code becomes harder to debug, since anyone can modify `a` and `b` at any time.

*Ideally*, functions should communicate exclusively through parameters, return values, and exceptions (where applicable); there are times where sharing state is the right answer, but those are relatively few and far between.

Since you're obviously using a C++ compiler, I'm going to do this the C++ way, using references instead of pointers.  I'm also going to use C++ `iostream` routines instead of `cstdio` (write either C or C++; trying to mix the two only leads to heartburn).

vars.hpp:

```
#ifndef VARS_H  // Include guard to prevent multiple inclusion
#define VARS_H

void double_vars(int &, float &);

#endif
```

vars.cpp:

```
#include "vars.hpp"

void double_vars(int &x, float &y)
{
  x *= 2;    
  y *= 2.0;  
}
```

main.cpp:

```
#include <iostream>
#include "vars.hpp"

int main(void)
{
  int a = 1;
  float b = 2.2;

  std::cout << "a: " << a << "; b: " << b << std::endl;
  double_vars(a, b);
  std::cout << "a: " << a << "; b: " << b << std::endl;

  return 0;
}
```

Since `x` and `y` were declared as *reference* types (using the `&`), writing to the *expressions* `x` and `y` in `double_vars` is equivalent to writing to `a` and `b` in `main`.

The C way of doing this would be with pointers instead of references:

vars.h:

```
#ifndef VARS_H  // Include guard to prevent multiple inclusion
#define VARS_H

void double_vars(int *, float *); 
#endif
```

vars.c:

```
#include "vars.h"

void double_vars(int *x, float *y)
{
  *x *= 2;    
  *y *= 2.0;  
}
```

main.c:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include "vars.h"

int main(void)
{
  int a = 1;
  float b = 2.2;

  printf("a: %d; b: %f\n", a, b);
  double_vars(&a, &b);
  printf("a: %d; b: %f\n", a, b);
  return 0;
}
```

In this case, we're using pointers instead of references, so we need to pass the result of the *expressions* `&a` and `&b` to `double_vars`; within the function, writing to the expressions `*x` and `*y` is the same as writing to `a` and `b` in `main`.

Comment: Agreed, your approach is much safer and better a programming practice. Need to get this above the other two answers so people will read this post instead .