# using same variable in diffrent source files C++

Tags: c++, global-variables, static-members

Is there any way to use from two diffrent source files the same instance of variable in `C++` ?

for example,if I have

**source1.cpp**

```
x = true;
while (x) 
{

}
```

**source2.cpp**

```
x = false;
```

then if I run first `source1.cpp`,there is infinite loop,and after runing `source2.cpp` from diffrent terminal,the loops end,due to x changes.

thanks.

**just to make it clear : those are two main files compiled separate from each other and run at the same time from two diffrent terminals**

Comment: That is called an "extern variable"

Comment: Can you extend how to do it? I try a lot with extern or static and nothing really worked

Comment: Re ["should be run from two diffrent terminals at the same time"](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/41518583/using-same-variable-in-diffrent-source-files-c#comment70243893_41518930), are you talking about two different programs, or two different processes of the same program, or two different translation units in the same program?

Comment: two diffrent programs(server program and client program)

Comment: @Matan: then, you are asking about a total different problem, which is how to share a variable between separate processes.  I suggest you rewrite your question in that sense.

Comment: @Matan:  If the main idea of having both a client and a server app is sharing _x_, then your apps are missing the entire client and server implementations.  There are many examples of such applications around on the internet.  You should visit this page http://www.thegeekstuff.com/2011/12/c-socket-programming/?utm_source=feedburner to get an idea on how it's done.

Answer (score 0):

"The global variable should be declared extern in a header file included by both source files, and then defined in only one of those source files" Check out [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3627941/global-variable-within-multiple-files)

Comment: I've tried this already, my problem is that source1.cpp and source2.cpp are two diffrent main files compiled seperate from each other.and then it should be run from two diffrent terminals at the same time,as I wrote in the first msg

Comment: ahh my apologies. how about you write and read to a static file? or is that to insecure for what you are dealing with?

Comment: well I thought about doing this,but I will use it only in case no other solution in C++ exist

Comment: Yeah I agree it's a last resort. Wish i was more help. Good luck.