# Initialize with global variables in c++

Tags: c++, inheritance, global-variables

I've tried to read the thread below about creating global variables that can be used between multiple files but it will not work.

[Global Variable within Multiple Files](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3627941/)

**variable.h**

```cpp
extern const int variable1;
```

**file1.h**

```cpp
class fileOne{
private:
    fileTwo ft[variable1];
    
public:
    //some functions...
};
```

**file2.h**

```cpp
class fileTwo{
private:
    //some variables
    
public:
    //some functions
};
```

**main.cpp**

```cpp
int main(){
    int variable1 = 2;
    fileOne fo;
}
```

When I run this, the compiler says the following:

> error: array bound is not an integer constant before ']' token

Is it possible to declare a global variable and use it in the manner above?

Also: Is this an array? `fileTwo ft[variable1];` Is fileTwo a class?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To define an array you need to specify the actual size of the array and the size must be something the compiler can turn into a constant. Since `variable1` can't be turned into a constant, the compiler issues the error.

What you can do is something like the following.

**file1.h**

```
class fileOne{
private:
    fileTwo ft[variable1];

public:
    //some functions...
};
```

**file2.h**

```
class fileTwo{
private:
    //some variables

public:
    //some functions
};
```

**main.cpp**

```
static const  int variable1 = 2;  // const int for the size of the ft array of class fileOne

#include "file2.h"  // class fileTwo definition is needed for class fileOne
#include "file1.h"  // class fileOne has a dependency on class fileTwo

int main(){
    fileOne fo;  // define a fileOne object named fo

    // do more stuff
}
```

Answer (score 1):

A fixed-sized array needs to have its size specified at compile-time, which means only a compile-time constant can be used.  You can't use an `extern`ed variable for the size of the array, even if it is declared as `const`, as the compiler simply doesn't know the actual value of the variable since it is in another translation unit.

Also, in `main.cpp`, you can't declare the `extern`'ed variable as a local variable, it needs to be in global scope instead.

For what you are trying to do, there is no reason to use `extern` at all.  Just declare `variable1` with a constant value directly in `variable.h`, and then `#include` that file where needed, eg:

variable.h:

```cpp
#ifndef VARIABLE_H
#define VARIABLE_H

static const int variable1 = 2;

#endif
```

file1.h:

```cpp
#ifndef FILE1_H
#define FILE1_H

#include "file2.h"
#include "variable.h"

class fileOne{
private:
    fileTwo ft[variable1];

public:
    //some functions...
};

#endif
```

file2.h:

```cpp
#ifndef FILE2_H
#define FILE2_H

class fileTwo{
private:
    //some variables

public:
    //some functions
};

#endif
```

main.cpp:

```cpp
#include "file1.h"

int main(){
    fileOne fo;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

> Is it possible to declare a global variable and use it in the manner above?

Yes, but like Remy pointed out, you would need to move this variable to a header file that will be `#include`d from `file1.h`

> Also: Is this an array? `fileTwo ft[variable1];`

Yes, this is called a C-array. The C++ standard library also has C++ arrays (i.e. fixed size) using `std::array<type, size>`, which are much more convenient and safe to use, as well as containers like `vector`, `list`, etc.

If you want to use a C++ array, you can declare it this way for you case:

```
#include <array>

std::array ft<fileTwo, variable1>;
```