# Testing a singleton class launching a threadpool

Tags: c++, static, global-variables, singleton, threadpool

I am using the `concurrent_queue<T>` and `ThreadPool` from

https://codereview.stackexchange.com/questions/288042/c-implementation-of-a-concurrent-queue-and-of-a-thread-pool/288044?noredirect=1#comment573780_288044

in a singleton class ``MySingleton` defined as follows :

```
class MySingleton
{
private:
    static MySingleton* pinstance_;
    static std::mutex mutex_;
protected:
    MySingleton()
    {
        ThreadPool::getInstance()->start(std::thread::hardware_concurrency() - 1);
    }
    ~MySingleton()
    {
        ThreadPool::getInstance()->stop();
    }
public:
    MySingleton(const MySingleton& rhs) = delete;
    MySingleton& operator=(const MySingleton& rhs) = delete;
    MySingleton(MySingleton&& rhs) = delete;
    MySingleton& operator=(MySingleton&& rhs) = delete;

    static MySingleton* GetInstance();
    
    double myMethod(/*input*/)
    {
        // stuff
    }
};

MySingleton* MySingleton::pinstance_{ nullptr };
std::mutex MySingleton::mutex_;

inline MySingleton* MySingleton::GetInstance()
{
    std::lock_guard<std::mutex> lock(mutex_);
    if (pinstance_ == nullptr)
    {
        pinstance_ = new MySingleton();
    }
    return pinstance_;
}
```

The member function `myMethod` calls another function that basically does a `ThreadPool* pool = ThreadPool::getInstance();` copies from the main thread all the other threads need, reserves memory for futures in a `std::vector<ThreadPool::TaskHandle>` and does

```
futures.push_back(pool->spawnTask([&, /*needed stuff*/]()
{
    // operations
}
);
```

and then waits for all futures :

```
for (auto& future : futures) pool->activeWait(future);
```

This all takes place in the very same DLL (and `MySingleton` is defined in an header file `MySingleton.h`), works as intended in production, and has been tested in a googletest exectutable which also works has intended.

Precisely, all google tests testing `double myMethod(/*input*/)` are in the same client code test source file `test1.cpp` looking like this :

```
#include "MySingleton.h"

MySingleton* mySingleton = MySingleton::GetInstance();

TEST(MyMethodsTest, SomeTest)
{
    const double result = mySingleton->myMethod(/*input of type A*/);
    constexpr double expect = 3.14159;
    ASSERT_NEAR(result, expect, 1e-5);
}
```

Now, I came to a point where the `myMethod`'s inputs are of very different nature so that I really want to separate my tests in different test files or classes so that I created a second test source file `test2.cpp` looking without surprise like this :

```
#include "MySingleton.h"

MySingleton* mySingleton = MySingleton::GetInstance();

TEST(MyMethodsTest2, SomeOtherTest)
{
    const double result = mySingleton->myMethod(/*input of type B*/);
    constexpr double expect = 6.28318;
    ASSERT_NEAR(result, expect, 1e-5);
}
```

It compiles fine but at linking I get errors in `test2`'s object files :

```
Error   LNK2005 "private: static unsigned __int64 ThreadPool::my_tls_num_" (?my_tls_num_@ThreadPool@@0_KA) already defined in test1.obj
Error   LNK2005 "private: static class ThreadPool ThreadPool::instance_" (?instance_@ThreadPool@@0V1@A) already defined in test1.obj    1   
Error   LNK2005 "class MySingleton * mySingleton" (?mySingleton) already defined in test1.obj
```

Logical, `test2.cpp`'s `mySingleton` is already defined in `test1.cpp`. Would I rename `test2.cpp`s `mySingleton` into `mySingleton2` I would have the following errors :

```
Error   LNK2005 "private: static unsigned __int64 ThreadPool::my_tls_num_" (?my_tls_num_@ThreadPool@@0_KA) already defined in test1.obj
Error   LNK2005 "private: static class ThreadPool ThreadPool::instance_" (?instance_@ThreadPool@@0V1@A) already defined in test1.obj
```

Logical also, as after all, it is a singleton.

I would like to define `mySingleton` only one time (in `test1.cpp` for instance) and use this unique definition in `test2.cpp` and all potential other tests source files, but I don't know how to proceed.

I guess that one part of the problem is that including `MySingleton.h` two times already leads to an issue as then all static variable in it will be defined two times (one in both place of inclusion), but I don't know how to exploit this guess : I naively only left `MySingleton` static variables declaration in `MySingleton.h` and created a `MySingelton.cpp` source file in which I defined them. This led at compilation to many errors that I was basically able to solve only by also including MySingleton.cpp in each source file where MySingleton.h was included (except in MySingleton.cpp of course), which smells horribly bad, but anyway it sorted out the compilation issue. But not the linking ones.

Of course, at this point in test, I still have a singleton defined two times (with the same name or not) in test1.cpp and test2.cpp. So what I did is that followed the advice from this answer :

https://stackoverflow.com/a/3627979/9510227

and created a header file singleton_def.h in which I declared `extern MySingleton* mySingleton;`, left `mySingleton`'s definition where it was in test1.cpp (only included singleton_def.h in it), removed ``mySingleton`'s from test2.cpp and included singleton_def.h in it and ... still had same errors.