# c++ undefined reference when declaring extern global variable in a namespace

Tags: c++, linker

I have a class where a "define" my app `compose-app.cpp`

```
#include <framework/framework_module.hpp>
#include <framework/logging/logging_module.hpp>

#include <hal/dma/dma_module.hpp>

namespace bla::application
{
    using namespace framework;
    using namespace framework::logging;

    using namespace hal::dma;

    framework_module framework_module_;
    io_module io_module_(framework_module_);

    dma_module dma_module_(framework_module_);
    ...
    ...
    // many other objects are constructed here
}
```

Pretty much my entire application is using class/structs, but a few files are just standard cpp files with some functions. For example, log.cpp.

In log.cpp I want to use a global variable, which shouldn't be a problem, I can simply declare the variable as `extern` and I'm done. Well, that's what I thought anyway.

log.cpp (simplified):

```
#include <etl/string.h>
#include <etl/to_string.h>

#include <framework/framework_module.hpp>
#include <framework/logging/logging_module.hpp>

extern xxx::framework::framework_module framework_module_;

namespace xxx::framework::logging
{
    static xxx::framework::free_rtos::ifree_rtos &_free_rtos = framework_module_._free_rtos;

    static SemaphoreHandle_t _semaphore;

    void initialize()
    {
        _semaphore = _free_rtos.create_counting_semaphore(1, 1);
    }
}
```

I thought this should be fine, but it gives the following linker error

```
/opt/gcc-arm-none-eabi/bin/../lib/gcc/arm-none-eabi/13.2.1/../../../../arm-none-eabi/bin/ld: CMakeFiles/app.dir/home/dev/app/source/framework/log.cpp.obj: in function `xxx::framework::logging::initialize()':
/home/dev/app/source/framework/log.cpp:57:(.text._ZN7valinso9framework7logging10initializeEv+0x2c): undefined reference to `xxx::framework::framework_module_'
```

It states, undefined reference to 'xxx:framework::framework_module_'. But that's the correct namespace for the type `framework_module`

```
#if !defined (unittests)

#pragma once

#include <framework/project.h>
#include <framework/project_definitions.hpp>

#include <framework/free_rtos/free_rtos.hpp>
#include <framework/irq/irq_handler_installer.hpp>
#include <framework/free_rtos/exclusive_lock.hpp>
#include <framework/free_rtos/read_write_lock.hpp>

namespace xxx::framework
{
    class framework_module
    {
    public:
        framework_module();

        free_rtos::free_rtos _free_rtos;
        irq::irq_handler_installer _irq_handler_installer;
    };
}

#endif
```

I have dealt with this before, and I remember vaguely that this had to do with the namespace where the variable is *defined*. But I can't seem to get this right. I've tried to move the extern variable definition inside the namespace, but that doesn't solve the problem.

To be honest, I simply don't understand how the compiler/linker deals with namespaces for extern variables, which doesn't help to solve this issue...

Comment: Can you please try to create a [mre] to show us? Especially, don't forget neither the definition nor the actual declaration.

Comment: `extern xxx::framework::framework_module framework_module_;` declares a global variable.  `namespace bla::application { ...; framework_module framework_module_; ...;}` defines a variable inside a namespace.  Those two objects are different.

Comment: Typically you delcare the variable as extern in a header file and then in one cpp file you define it.  If you have C++17 or newer it is even simpler and you just define the variable in the header file and add to the declaration the `inline` specifier.

Comment: Right, I can read what you write. And I soort of get it. But how should I declare the extern variabele so that the compiler treats it as the same object?

Comment: I am using c++20, I'll read your comment a couple of times and give it a try

Comment: If you want to use `extern`, see this: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3627941/global-variable-within-multiple-files.  I'm lstill looking for a good link for `inline`

Comment: Here is a link if for `inline`: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38043442/how-do-inline-variables-work

Comment: Don't post error messages in quote blocks. Post them in code blocks to keep their format.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In `compose-app.cpp`, you are defining a variable named `framework_module_` of type `xxx::framework::framework_module` and putting that variable in the namespace `bla::application`.

But, in `log.cpp`, you are declaring an `extern`'d variable named `framework_module_` of type `xxx::framework::framework_module` that exists in the global namespace.  But there is no such variable defined in the global namespace, hence the linker error.  You need to reference the variable that is located in the `bla::application` namespace instead.

```
namespace bla::application
{
    extern xxx::framework::framework_module framework_module_;
}
```

```
namespace xxx::framework::logging
{
    using namespace bla::application;
    static xxx::framework::free_rtos::ifree_rtos &_free_rtos = framework_module_._free_rtos;
    ...
}
```

[Online Demo](https://onlinegdb.com/rntrP5lvF)

Comment: I finally got it resolved. Went for the header approach. But thanks a lot for the explanation. Clear, and now it looks simple. But it wasn't ;-). Not in my head anyway :)

Answer (score 0):

As `framework_module_` is declared now, you should extend namespace `bla::application` into `log.cpp`, because fully-qualified name is `bla::application::framework_module_`:

```
namespace bla::application {
   extern xxx::framework::framework_module framework_module_;
}
```

whole thing looks like a snake biting own tail though.It's better to considera a third site which would contain application-specific globals.